# Here is some Applescript code to interact with Microsoft Excel on Snow Leopard - How to add the missing functions

Tags: excel, applescript, osx-snow-leopard, automator

I have about 400 excel files. I want to insert a column just before the first column in the existing file and then insert the name of the file into each row of that column.

I know a little bit of Applescript and based on that I wrote this script so that I can drop some files onto the script and it will execute the script on each one of those files.

I was wondering if someone could help me in completing the "TO DO" lines. Upon execution this script gives me dialogue boxes with the path of files that I drop on top. But the excel application throws an error dialogue box which says" Not enough memory". I tried this with only 2 excel files so it wasn't the number of files that caused the error.

Can someone please give me a hand with completing the TODO lines and give me an ide as to why Im getting the error. Thanks

```
property numFiles : 0

on open excelFiles


set fileNames to ""

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with eachFile in excelFiles

        --open document file eachFile

        --tell application "Microsoft Excel"

        --increment count



        --save name of each file

        set fileNames to fileNames & return & (POSIX path of eachFile)

        --TO DO insert a column

        --TO DO insert text in each column to the name of eachFile

        --end tell
    end repeat
    display dialog fileNames
    --display dialog "Ouch that hurt " & return & "You dropped " & (count excelFiles) & "files on me"
end tell
end open

on addFilePath(eachFile)
set fileNames to fileNames & (POSIX path of eachFile)
end addFilePath
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand everything --> insert the name of the file into each row of that column | **TO DO** insert text in ***each column*** to the name of eachFile.

Here is the script, **Updated :**

```
    on open excelFiles
    set numFiles to count excelFiles
    repeat with eachFile in excelFiles -- open each file in Excel
        tell application "Microsoft Excel"
            set tBook to open workbook workbook file name (eachFile as string)
            set tName to name of tBook
            insert into range column 1 of active sheet -- insert column

            set lastCell to last cell of used range of active sheet -- get last cell from the used range
            set value of range ("A1:A" & first row index of lastCell) of active sheet to tName --set first column's values to the file name

            close tBook saving yes
        end tell
    end repeat
    display dialog numFiles
end open
```

Edit : I forgot the error :

**Not enough memory** : This weird error seems to be :  you call a handler without  using `my` or `tell me to`) in a `tell block application`.

Use **my** like this : `set x to my addFilePath(eachFile)`

Also, a  `tell application "Microsoft Excel"` block in the  `application Finder` block is not recommended, this can cause unexpected errors.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment, but it was deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Im still trying to write this script. Your solution is what Im using as a guide. I will accept your ans and then also post my  solution